# android relise apk не работет youtube

Tags: android, youtube

Проблема состоит в том, что написали приложение в котором используется библиотека **YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar**, которая позволяет просматривать видео с youtube.

Пока приложение находилось в стадии дебага то все отлично работало, но после создания релизного apk файла и выкладывания его на google play перестал работать youtube.

Путем нехитрых манипуляций удалось выяснить, что проблема неработающего youtube состоит в том, что приходит какой-то неправильный токен для запроса на youtube. Для получения данного токина испольуется google+ аккаунт. Соответственно к запросу добавляется вот такой скоуп `oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube`, тип аккаунта `com.google` и имя аккаунта. На запрос приходит вот такая вот ошибка:

> "code": 403, "message": "Access Not Configured. The API (YouTube Data API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration."

Хочу повторится, что все работает до того момента как создается релизный apk файл.

Comment: Тут смотрели?.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22872526/3212712 и тут: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27491718/3212712?

Comment: Если пользоваться вот этой ссылкод https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=<TOKEN google+> для проверки токeна то возникает вопрос почему "access_type": "offline" в релизном apk и online в дебажном где все работает нормально.

P.S. вопрос остался открытый, были прописанны и дебажные и релизные ключи, ссылки на другие темы тоже не помогли, все предложенные варианты не работаю. Начали тестить на другой google developer console но проблема осталась

Comment: Решение проблемы нашлось путем научного тыка. В google developer console заходим Credential -> Add credentials -> OAuth 2.0 client ID и создаем ключ, после чего ждем пол часа, а за это время добавляем скоупы запроса регистрации. Всем благдарен за предложенные варианты решения проблемы

Comment: опубликуйте, пожалуйста, своё решение в качестве ответа - это поможет людям, кои в будущем столкнутся с этой проблемой.

Answer (score 3):

Возможно проблема в ключах. Скорей всего вы прописали только дебажные ключи для работы с API, пропишите также ключ в Google Developer Console которым вы подписываете релизное приложение.
[Здесь](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/register) можно посмотреть как это сделать.